# Border radius not dependent on height and width

Tags: css, sass, border

I need a border-radius rule that will make that element will be rounded the same not matter what is the size(height) of the element.

Here is my example:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="element first"></div>
  <div class="element sec"></div>
  <div class="element third"></div>
</div>


$blue: #0084ff;

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;

  .element {
    background-color: $blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

    &.first{
      height: 50px;
    }

    &.sec{
      height: 150px;
    }

    &.third{
      height: 250px;
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ballkar/75tda12q/29/

Here is effect that I need to achive:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to apply he `border-radius: 25px;` instead of `border-radius: 100px;`.

for more understanding look the following snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.element {
  background-color: #0084ff;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.element.first {
  height: 50px;
}

.element.sec {
  height: 150px;
}

.element.third {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element first"></div>
  <div class="element sec"></div>
  <div class="element third"></div>
</div>
```

Following is the sass code for you:

```
$blue: #0084ff;
$blue-darker: darken($blue, 5);

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;

  .element {
    background-color: $blue;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

    &.first{
      height: 50px;
    }

    &.sec{
      height: 150px;
    }

    &.third{
      height: 250px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's still the same, look at my question I added graphic what I need to achieve.

Comment: look my edited ans and edited sass code I have just edit it.

Comment: Thank you, but to be honest I have no idea why it's working with value 25px but not with value 100px.

Comment: because you are using sort hand property to apply border-radius so it will apply radius to all 4 corners of your box so all corner radius should be 100px. remember one thing while you have to apply border-radius to any box with its fix height then your box border-radius should be the half of your box height for example you first box height is 50px so the border-radius should be 50px / 2 = 25px.

Comment: You also used short hand property in you example, and it worked.

I don't know the height of the box and thats all about.

Comment: ya I have also use the sort-hand property but I use value of border-radius half then the height of the box.